# How to clear selected value of angular-timezone-selector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using the angular-timezone-selector (https://github.com/mishguruorg/angular-timezone-selector) and I want to have the selector revert to the placeholder after every selection.

If you look at the plunkr demo, the standard functionality is to display the last selected choice, but what I want is for it to continue to display the placeholder before and after every choice the user makes.

Thanks in advance.